# simple Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

A Lie group is a group which is a smooth manifold such that the multiplication and inversion are smooth.

When does a Lie group become simple?
What is the difference between simple and semi-simple Lie group?

Just want a quick answer here.
Thanks

Comment: [Wikipedia's *Simple Lie Group* entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#Comments_on_the_definition) comments on the varied definitions.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Lie group is a Lie group that contains no $connected$ normal subgroups.  This is not the same as being a Lie group which is simple as an abstract group.  For example the real numbers under addition are a simple Lie group, but have plenty of discrete normal subgroups (the integers for example), and even dense normal subgroups (like the rational numbers) which are disconnected under the subspace topology.

Comment: You forgot to exclude 1-dimendional  (abelian) groups, they are usually not regarded as being simple.